# Add docusign API create and send envelope method

Tags: docusignapi

could you please suggest me where to write soap header in my code.When i tried to write in my webconfig under   it is not allowed there and give error as "Namespace prefix 'soap' is not defined."
And when i tried to write in my .cshtml  code of controller in which i have included "using HIPAAtrek.DocuSignAPI;"
and also added Docusign API threw 'Service Reference' it gives error as "Unrecognized namespace soap".

Answer (score 0):

Here is code you can use to call REST API: http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthroughs

9 most popular scenarios.